# Laravel link to action destroy not working

Tags: laravel, show, destroy

I am not sure why but this is acting as a show method.  Please help.

```
{{ link_to_action('QuestionsController@destroy', 'Delete', $question->id) }}    

// In my QuestionsController
public function destroy($question_id)
{
    return 'hello';
}
```

Since I'm linking to the delete method directly, I don't have to use a form with a route with a delete method.  Is this right?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you use this?

Comment: Because you need `post` form with pseudo `delete` http method like in the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form. Unless you're not using default laravel routes of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Because you need post form with pseudo delete http method like in the
>   docs: laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form. Unless you're not
>   using default laravel routes of course. –  Jarek Tkaczyk

This was the solution, thank you!

Comment: You should give Jarek a chance to answer if this solved the problem. If he decided this wasn't a good enough answer then maybe you could grab it like that but I would allow him the chance to get the credit if he solved your problem.